# glVertexPointer invalid operation

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm having rather strange problem with OpenGL. When I try to use `glVertexPointer` with no buffer bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` and using Vertex Array Object(VAO), it generates invalid operation error. This error is nowhere in documentation of `glVertexPointer`.

When I generate buffer and bind it to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`, error disappears, but as I have my data stored on RAM, I bind 0 and use pointer to RAM. Also by not binding VAOs I don't get error anymore, but I've noticed that when I don't use it, my other things further in program gets corrupted.

Maybe I've missed somewhere that setting pointers, while VAO is bound and buffer is not, is going to be invalid invalid operation? Theoretically I could move those data to VBOs and don't bother, but I'd like to know why's this happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extension registry for [ARB_vertex_array_object](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/vertex_array_object.txt) clearly states, that they cannot be used with client-side arrays. This shouldn't be different for the core OpenGL versions supporting VAOs and is due to the fact, that VAOs are server-state. So it is completely expected behaviour to get an invalid operation error. Just store everything in VBOs (maybe using `GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW` or `GL_STREAM_DRAW` as usage if the data changes frequently).

Comment: Did you mean `GL_STREAM_DRAW` instead of `GL_STATIC_DRAW`?  The former is for things that change very frequently (e.g. every frame); the latter is for things that *rarely* change.

Comment: Thanks, I must've missed it while I was reading through that page.